# goto vs. switch vs. your own way!! which is your choice for readability

Tags: algorithm, implementation, goto

[you can notice that it may be flowchart or state machine transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVqNT.png)

I am wondering which is the better option to implement the above flowchart of a algorithm.

I think go to is better solution.

How do you think so? I want to know your opinions.

### [goto version]

```
main () {
    if ( condition == a )
        goto A:
    elif ( condition == b )
        B();
    elif ( condition == c )
        C();
    elif (condition == e )
        E();

    A:
    // do something

    B:
    if ( condition == c )
        // do something
        goto C;
    elif ( condition == d )
        // do somthing
        goto D;

    C:
    if ( condition == d )
        // do something
        goto D;

    D:
    if ( condition == a)
        // do something
        goto A;
    elif ( condition == e)
        // do something
        goto E;

    E:
        // do something

    return;
}
```

### [function call version with switch case grammar]

```
main () {
    switch (condition) {
        case a:
            A();
            break;
        case b:
            B();
            break;
        case c:
            C();
            break;
        case e:
            E();
            break;
    }
}

fuction A() {
    // do something

    switch (condition) {
        case b:
            B();
            break;  
    }
}

function B() {
    // do something

    switch (condition) {
        case c:
            C();
            break;
        case d:
            D();
            break;
    }

}

function C() {
    // do something

    switch (condition) {
        case d:
            D();
            break;
        }

}

function D() {
    // do something

    switch (condition) {
        case a:
            A();
            break;
        case e:
            E();
            break;
    }
}

function E() {
    // do something
    return ;
}
```

### [add your way to implement and handle all the execution path]

Comment: good. I only focus on the readability and maintenance of the codes. 

do you mean that the goto version is better choice?

Comment: in terms of simplicity only: Yes

Comment: Thanks. good. that's what I want to confirm.

But there is a saying that don't use goto because it seems to be messy. 

how do you think about with that?

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental. If `condition == a`, you go to A and do something. Then you fall through to B and check `condition` again. But you already know that `condition` is `a`. You do all kinds of fall through and condition checks for no good reason. Unless your `do something` is modifying the value of `condition`. If that's the case, you've written what we call [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), and you need some serious remedial help.

Comment: I didn't have enough explanation about the condition. 
I assume that the value of the variable condition can be changed time to time like a sensor module. 

so even if nothing happen to the variable, condition, in the // do something part. It can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a lot better like this:

```
main () {
    if ( condition != a ) {
        if ( condition == b )
            B();
        elif ( condition == c )
            C();
        elif (condition == e )
            E();
    }

    for (;;) {
        // do something (A)

        if ( condition == c ) {
            // do something
            if ( condition == d )
                // do something
        }
        elif ( condition == d )
            // do somthing
        if ( condition != a)
            break;
        // do something
    }
    if ( condition == e)
        // do something

    // do something

    return;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to your first version.  I'm not gonna verify that your second version is the same, because it's hard to read, and I wouldn't say that it necessarily implements the state machine you link to.

Comment: I read you codes. 
so you agree with the 1 thing as I want to tell.
- the function call version with if statement is not good for readability. 

However It is hard for me to get that your codes is more readable for people. 

and You don't seem to consider the execute paths from B and D. 
B and D have two different execution paths. 

So in your codes It isn't considered yet. 

can you make more perfect code with B,D?

Comment: I just added my 2nd of goto version. 

How do you think? is my codes better for readability?
or still yours is more better for readability to understand the codes.

Comment: @elsdy your new version is a lot better, because it's obvious that it's a state machine.  You should improve it by only doing transitions one way -- if you're going to use goto for state transitions, then use it all the time, instead of falling through.

Answer (score 0):

I write the better version compare to the my goto version
I call it 2nd verion of go to.

I think It is more better readability.

How do you think about that?

### [the 2nd version using goto]

```
main () {
    if ( condition == a )
        goto A:
    elif ( condition == b )
        B();
    elif ( condition == c )
        C();
    elif (condition == e )
        E();

    A:
    // do something

    B:
    if ( condition == d )
        // do somthing
        goto D;

    C:
        // do something

    D:
    if ( condition == a)
        // do something
        goto A;

    E:
        // do something

    return;
}
```